# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG error on virtual server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

hello everyone i am having few problems with configuring apache2 firstly i am using ubuntu server as a virtual machine and using

> port forwarding to forward host>8080 to guest>80

i also installed virtual box guest addition to use a shared folder called "sandbox", i made a configuration file called

> "vboxsf" in "/apache2/sites-available"

to make the apache access the content found in the shared folder ,and also run these commands

```
 sudo a2ensite vbox.sf
 sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

and enabled few modes "rewrite,status" also edited the host file on my host to 127.0.0.1 sandbox.dev

now when i try to access for example http://sandbox.dev:8080 or http://sandbox.dev/server-status/ this error occur [pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwpQm.jpg)

Content of `vboxsf.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
  ServerName sandbox
  ServerAlias *.dev

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-access.log combined

  RewriteEngine On

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /media/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Location>

  UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /media/sf_%1
</VirtualHost>
```

using

```
curl http://sandbox.dev:8080/server-status
```

gets the html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.dev` TLD's been forced into HTTPS by Chrome and Firefox:

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

So use something else for testing. `http://sandbox/` ought to work; does that also show an error?

Comment: nope it does not show the error anymore thank you very much :)